# I am getting this error while executing Chef Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed

Tags: chef-infra, f5

When I execute Chef recipe through the work station I always get this error and I'm not able to understand what is missing?

```
> knife bootstrap 10.192.74.59 --ssh-user scs --ssh-password 'cisco123' --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name webserver10.192.74.59 --run-list 'recipe[f5-node-initiator]'  
> Node webserver10.192.74.59 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) Y  
> Client webserver10.192.74.59 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) Y  
> Creating new client for webserver10.192.74.59  
> Creating new node for webserver10.192.74.59  
> Connecting to 10.192.74.59  
> 10.192.74.59 [sudo] password for scs: -----> Existing Chef installation detected
10.192.74.59 Starting the first Chef Client run...
10.192.74.59 Starting Chef Client, version 12.15.19
10.192.74.59 resolving cookbooks for run list: ["f5-node-initiator"]
10.192.74.59 Synchronizing Cookbooks:
10.192.74.59   - f5-node-initiator (0.0.1)
10.192.74.59 Installing Cookbook Gems:
10.192.74.59 Compiling Cookbooks...
10.192.74.59 Converging 4 resources
10.192.74.59 Recipe: f5-node-initiator::default
10.192.74.59   * cookbook_file[/var/chef/cache/f5-icontrol-10.2.0.2.gem] action create (up to date)
10.192.74.59   * cookbook_file[/usr/local/bin/f5-node-initiator] action create (up to date)
10.192.74.59   * gem_package[f5-icontrol] action install (up to date)
10.192.74.59   * execute[f5-node-initiator] action run
10.192.74.59     
10.192.74.59     ================================================================================
10.192.74.59     Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[f5-node-initiator]'
10.192.74.59     ================================================================================
10.192.74.59     
10.192.74.59     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
10.192.74.59     ------------------------------------
10.192.74.59     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
10.192.74.59     ---- Begin output of f5-node-initiator -b 10.192.73.79 -u  -p  -n  -d 10.192.74.59:80 ----
10.192.74.59     STDOUT: 
10.192.74.59     STDERR: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/charset.rb:13: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective
10.192.74.59     /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/xmlparser.rb:74:in `<top (required)>': XML processor module not found. (RuntimeError)
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
10.192.74.59        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/parser.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
10.192.74.59        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/wsdlDriver.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
10.192.74.59        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/f5-icontrol-10.2.0.2/lib/f5-icontrol.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
10.192.74.59        from /usr/local/bin/f5-node-initiator:31:in `<main>'
10.192.74.59     ---- End output of f5-node-initiator -b 10.192.73.79 -u  -p  -n  -d 10.192.74.59:80 ----
10.192.74.59     Ran f5-node-initiator -b 10.192.73.79 -u  -p  -n  -d 10.192.74.59:80 returned 1
10.192.74.59     
10.192.74.59     Resource Declaration:
10.192.74.59     ---------------------
10.192.74.59     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/f5-node-initiator/recipes/default.rb
10.192.74.59     
10.192.74.59      25: execute "f5-node-initiator" do
10.192.74.59      26:   command "f5-node-initiator -b #{node[:bigip][:address]} -u #{node[:bigip][:user]} -p #{node[:bigip][:pass]} -n #{node[:bigip][:pool_name]} -d #{node[:bigip][:node_address]}:#{node[:bigip][:node_port]}"
10.192.74.59      27:  # action :nothing
10.192.74.59      28: end
10.192.74.59     
10.192.74.59     Compiled Resource:
10.192.74.59     ------------------
10.192.74.59     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/f5-node-initiator/recipes/default.rb:25:in `from_file'
10.192.74.59     
10.192.74.59     execute("f5-node-initiator") do
10.192.74.59       action [:run]
10.192.74.59       retries 0
10.192.74.59       retry_delay 2
10.192.74.59       default_guard_interpreter :execute
10.192.74.59       command "f5-node-initiator -b 10.192.73.79 -u  -p  -n  -d 10.192.74.59:80"
10.192.74.59       backup 5
10.192.74.59       returns 0
10.192.74.59       declared_type :execute
10.192.74.59       cookbook_name "f5-node-initiator"
10.192.74.59       recipe_name "default"
10.192.74.59     end
10.192.74.59     
10.192.74.59     Platform:
```

Comment: The author of this cookbook as started a new one [here](https://github.com/swalberg/chef-f5), this one sounds highly outdated, the main error is that a gem that was present in chef long ago is not there anymore, you may try to re-add it but I think it would be better to use the updated cookbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the soap4r gem. Given that soap4r has been abandoned for 9 years now, it seems unlikely to be fixed. You can find forked with this issue patched on GitHub and could install one of those instead in your recipe code.